# Capacity argument for logging.handlers.MemoryHandler

Tags: python

I have been using a `MemoryHandler` from Python's logging module, paired with a `FileHandler`, so that log messages go to the `MemoryHandler` during time-critical code and then are flushed to the `FileHandler` later. My setup code is:

```
logger = logging.getLogger('timing_log')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(message)s')
file_handler = logging.FileHandler('my_log.txt')
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
memory_loghandler = logging.handlers.MemoryHandler(
    capacity=10 * 1024,
    flushLevel=logging.ERROR,
    target=file_logger
)
memory_loghandler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(memory_loghandler)
```

And during time-critical parts of the code I log with:

```
logger.info('my logging message')
```

I'm a bit unsure about the `capacity` argument, however. Is this specifying the size in bytes, so my current value of `10 * 1024` gives a 10KB capacity? Also, if the buffer reaches its capacity, it should just flush and continue, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the implementation of [MemoryHandler as well as its base BufferingHandler](https://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Lib/logging/handlers.py):

- `capacity` specifies **count of the log records** that are hold in the buffer before being flushed
- yes, when the buffer reaches its capacity, it just flushes and continues (see BufferingHandler.emit)

Comment: Thanks, I thought capacity would have been specifying a size in bytes or bits, but it looks like you're right and it's the number of records.